# torch7: Obtaining the Frequency of an Element in a Tensor

Tags: lua, torch

I am looking for some **efficient** way (or a combination of ways) to count the number of instances (i.e. obtain **frequency**) of a given element in any general `torch.Tensor`.

By efficient, I mean something other than the trivial iterative method to search through each element of the given tensor and something which can take advantage of the parallelism offered by the GPUs.

I have looked at the documentation provided at **[tensor.md](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md)** and **[maths.md](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md)** but was not able to find something which could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just formulating Alex's comment as an answer. I found it useful for my own work. Example:

```
t = torch.Tensor({1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0})
frequency = t:eq(2):sum() -- frequency of 2 in t
```